# If $f$ is integrable, show that $f(x)$ is finite almost everywhere

Tags: measure-theory

If $f$ is integrable, show that $f(x)$ is finite almost everywhere.

I know that $f$ is integrable/finite if and only if $\vert f \vert$ is integrable/finite, so I only have to show it for $f \geq 0$. I think I should use the set $E = \{x \mid f(x)= \infty\}$ and show that its measure is zero, but I'm not sure why this shows that integrable implies finite a.e. or how to show that its measure is zero.

Comment: $\int_{f=\infty} fd\mu=\infty \mu (\{f=\infty\}=\infty$ if $\mu (\{f=\infty\} >0$.

Comment: You're going to have to actually dig into the details of exactly how the Lebesgue integral is defined. What definition are you using?

Comment: $\int f d \mu = \int f^+ d \mu - \int f^- d \mu$

Answer (score 2):

It suffices to show that $|f| < \infty$ almost everywhere since this implies $f < \infty$ almost everywhere.

Let $A = \{x: |f(x)| = +\infty\}$ and suppose $\mu(A) = M > 0$. For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $n \chi_{A}$ is a simple function and we have $0 \leq n \chi_{A} \leq |f|$, and so by definition of the Lebesgue integral for a non-negative function

$$
\int |f| \geq \sup_{n} \int n \chi_{A} = \sup_{n} nM = +\infty
$$
since $M > 0$. This contradicts the fact that $\int |f| < \infty$ so we conclude that $\mu(A) = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a good example where I think it is simpler working with the definition of the integral. Assume $\mu(E)>0$, and notice that for all $n$
$$ \phi_n(x)=n\cdot \mathbf{1}_E(x) $$
is a simple function satisfying that $\phi_n\leq f$. Now consider what the definition of $\int f d\mu$ for non-negative functions, and you can conclude that $\int fd\mu>M$ for all $M>0$.

Just to give some an alternative approach.